# how to pass options to a function using dplyr mutate_at

Tags: r, function, scale, dplyr

I want to center, but not standardize, a set of variables in a data frame. I tried the code for doing that using mutate_at, but the scale function uses `scale = TRUE` as default, and I can't figure out how to set it to `scale = FALSE`. Tis scales the desired variables, but standardizes in addition to centering:

```
centdata <- mydat %>% 
mutate_at(.vars = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 14), 
.funs = list("scaled" = scale))
```

Comment: I recommed to use `across´ instead of `mutate_at`, since it is a deprecated syntax

Comment: The tag at-command is about the Hayes Command Set. That doesn't apply here.

Comment: When posting an R question, try to include some data that should work with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use purrr style formula or an anonymous function here.

```
library(dplyr)
cols <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 14)

centdata <- mydat %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = cols, 
            .funs = list("scaled" = ~scale(., scale = FALSE)))
```

Since `mutate_at` has been deprecated, you can use `across`.

```
centdata <- mydat %>% 
  mutate(across(cols, list("scaled" = ~scale(., scale = FALSE))))
```

---

In base R -

```
mydat[paste0(names(mydat)[cols], '_scaled')] <- lapply(mydat[cols], scale, scale = FALSE)
```

`scale` also work on dataframe directly.

```
mydat[paste0(names(mydat)[cols], '_scaled')] <- scale(mydat[cols])
```